# Laravel: How to write a integration test for Notification that sends email

Tags: laravel, testing, notifications, integration-testing

How one would test email is sent as a final outcome after triggering a notification or doing an action that triggers notification?

Ideally, there is a notification merely for sending an email. My first thought was to trigger it and then check if `Mail::assertSent()` is sent. However, it appears that this does not work as Notification returns Mailable but does not invoke `Mail::send()`.

Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27848

My first approach for **test**:

```php
    /** @test */
    public function notification_should_send_email()
    {
        Mail::fake();
        Mail::assertNothingSent();

        // trigger notification
        Notification::route('mail', 'email@example.com')
            ->notify(new SendEmailNotification());

        Mail::assertSent(FakeMailable::class);
    }
```

while the Notification **toMail()** method looks as:

```php
    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\FakeMailable
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new FakeMailable())
            ->to($notifiable->routes['mail']);
    }
```

The set-up example is available https://github.com/flexchar/laravel_mail_testing_issue

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking#notification-fake

Comment: `Notification::fake()` is used for testing notifications themselves i.e. units not for feature tests. So not relevant.

Comment: Ah fair enough. I'd assumed that since you'd tried to use `Mail::fake();` you'd be ok using `Notification::fake();`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mailCatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/) then extends your TestCase

```
class MailCatcherTestCase extends TestCase
{
protected $mailCatcher;

/**
 * MailCatcherTestCase constructor.
 * @param $mailCatcher
 */
public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = ''
) {

    parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);

    $this->mailCatcher = new Client(['base_uri' => "http://127.0.0.1:1080"]);
}

protected function removeAllEmails() {
    $this->mailCatcher->delete('/messages');
}

protected function getLastEmail() {
    $emails = $this->getAllEmail();
    $emails[count($emails) - 1];
    $emailId = $emails[count($emails) - 1]['id'];

    return $this->mailCatcher->get("/messages/{$emailId}.json");
}

 protected function assertEmailWasSentTo($recipient, $email) {
    $recipients = json_decode(((string)$email->getBody()),
        true)['recipients'];
    $this->assertContains("<{$recipient}>", $recipients);
}

}
```

then you can use in you test

```
 /** @test */
public function notification_should_send_email()
{

    // trigger notification
    Notification::route('mail', 'email@example.com')
        ->notify(new SendEmailNotification());

    $email = $this->getLastEmail();
    $this->assertEmailWasSentTo($email, 'email@example.com');
}
```

since you can fetch the mail, so that you can test mail body, subject, cc, attachment etc.

don't forget to remove all mails in tearDown

hope this helps.

Comment: As last resort, it'd surely help, thanks! However at the same time it seems so overwhelming for testing relatively small and simple logic

Comment: Where does `Client` come from?!?